# Java application with Multi Pointer X support

Tags: java, swing, xorg

I'm wondering how multiple pointers should/could be handled by a java application. I think that Swing does not support [MPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Pointer_X). I found in google the [java-gnome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-gnome) library. Meybe it should be used?

I have java application which uses Swing and I want to use multi pointer on it. But there are some focus issues. What is the best way to rewrite Java Swing application to support MPX?

Comment: There's a technet presentation that speaks to multi-touch, where they mention it could work with multiple pointers also.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/ts-5546-159237.pdf  The interesting part starts around page 34